# My custom add_meta_box is not showing up in wordpress admin panel

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

New to Wordpress and struggling with the meta boxes. Unable to get my piece of code to work/show, nor was I able find examples that work. Nothing just wants to show up in the admin panel and have no clue what I'm missing / doing wrong.
Until now it looks like it's not triggering the callback function or something.

**What I want to do:**

Show a checkbox to hide the page's title

**What I see:**

No checkbox is showing up on the page edit screen

**My code in functions.php:**

```
function twentyseventeenchild_hide_title() {
    add_meta_box(
        'no-title', // Unique id
        __( 'Hide title' ), // Title
        'twentyseventeenchild_hide_title_callback', // Callback
        'post', // Screen (such as post type, link or comment)
        'normal', // Context (normal, advanced, side)
        'default' // Priority (default, core, high, low)
        // Callback arguments
    );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'twentyseventeenchild_hide_title' );

/**
 * Meta box display callback.
 *
 * @param WP_Post $post Current post object.
 */
function twentyseventeenchild_hide_title_callback( $post ) {
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_title', true);
    ?>
    <label><?php __('Hide title') ?></label>
    <input id="no_title" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" value="<?=esc_attr($meta)?>" name="page_title">
    <?php
}
```

Comment: If you want it to appear on page edit, Change the screen from `post` to `page`

Answer (score 3):

You're using checkbox incorrectly.

See input checkbox: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp
Your method need to be like:

```
    function twentyseventeenchild_hide_title_callback( $post ) {
        $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_title', true);
        ?>
            <input id="no_title" type="checkbox" <?php ($meta === '1' ? 'selected' : ''); ?> name="page_title">
            <label for="no_title"><?php _e('Hide title') ?></label>
        <?php
    }
```

`_e()` is for translate and echo, `__()` only return string and not print it.
`($meta === '1' ? 'selected' : '');` is because when you save metabox value `true`will be saved as string `1`. With this ternary you can show as selected this metabox if value is euqals 1 (as string).

Comment: Thanks! Totally forgot to change that (was a text field before for testing). Applied the changes, but still not showing up unfortunately.

Comment: Are you trying to show this meta box on custom post type or page? I use this code in my testing WordPress and shows the field under content editor.

Maybe you disable it on screen options. Click on "Screen Options" tab (top right) and check "Hide title".

Comment: I've found the checkbox after scrolling down on my page. It's now below the content part (don't know if this has anything to do with the Gutenberg editor). I expected it to show up in the panel on the right instead. That's why I didn't see it down there :x

Thanks for your help!